# DllImport in FSI

Tags: f#, mono, dllimport

Need to port following C# code to F#:

```
[DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int chmod(string pathname, int mode);
```

What is wrong in following code? Tried it in FSI on Mac and getting `error FS0193: internal error: Method 'FSI_0020+Libc.chmod' does not have a method body.`

```
module Libc =
    open System.Runtime.InteropServices
    [<DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)>]
    extern int chmod(string pathname, int mode)

    [<DllImport ("libc", EntryPoint = "chmod", SetLastError = true)>]
    extern int sys_chmod (string _path,  uint32 _mode)

    let chmodCarry mode path = sys_chmod(path, mode)
```

And what to do with `private` and `static` in this case? I would make sys_chmod private and expose the carried `chmod` function only.
Or is there any other more portable way to make a file executable?

Comment: When you say that you tried it, did you invoke the methods or just have them entered in FSI. In my Windows Visual Studio (Community 2013) FSI answers this (in case it helps you to know):

`module Libc = begin
  val chmod : pathname:string * mode:int -> int
  val sys_chmod : _path:string * _mode:uint32 -> int
  val chmodCarry : mode:uint32 -> path:string -> int
end`
(are block code quotes disabled in comments?)

Comment: No, I didn't invoked it because of error, just sent to FSI like it is (VSCode on mac). Now tried it on windows also and have no errors. But obviously can't invoke it on windows because of missing libc (DllNotFoundException)

Comment: Guess it must be a bug then.